# get by id from local json http

Tags: json, node.js, http

I have fake `users.json` file and I can `http.get` to list the array of json.
Since I want to get the particular user by id and haven't stored the data in the database, instead just use the fake `json` data.

```
[
  {
    "id": "cb55524d-1454-4b12-92a8-0437e8e6ede7",
    "name": "john",
    "age": "25",
    "country": "germany"
  },
  {
    "id": "ab55524d-1454-4b12-92a8-0437e8e6ede8",
    "name": "tom",
    "age": "28",
    "country": "canada"
  }
]
```

I can do this stuff if the data is stored in the database, but not sure how to proceed with the fake json data.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need the json as raw data, for just fake data, You can simply require it and use it as object..

```
const JsonObj = require('path/to/file.json')
console.log(JsonObj[0].id) // <-- cb55524d-1454-4b12-92a8-0437e8e6ede7
```

Plus, if you need more dynamic solution, there is a good JSON-server you can easily use for testing and so: [check this git repo](https://github.com/typicode/json-server)

Answer (score 1):

```
var _ = require('underscore');

var dummyJson = [
  {
    "id": "cb55524d-1454-4b12-92a8-0437e8e6ede7",
    "name": "john",
    "age": "25",
    "country": "germany"
  },
  {
    "id": "ab55524d-1454-4b12-92a8-0437e8e6ede8",
    "name": "tom",
    "age": "28",
    "country": "canada"
  }
]

var requiredID = "cb55524d-1454-4b12-92a8-0437e8e6ede7";

var reuiredObject = _.find(dummyJson, function (d) {
    return d.id === requiredID;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get JSON object using JSON.parse('users.json') and store it in a variable users.
2. Loop through array of users using `for .. in` and using `if` condition on `id` update the object if required.
3. Stringify the updated users object using JSON.stringify(users); and write this string to users.json file using `fs.write()` module in NodeJS so you will have updated objects in your json file.